# Copy table and append to larger archive table - google sheets script

Tags: google-sheets, append, copy-paste

I have a set of data on a sheet from cell C11 to column J with a dynamic number of rows.

What I am trying to do is simply copy that table of data to the first empty row on a different master sheet which begins A1:H at ever increasing length as these smaller tables get added to it.

Ideally I would like this set up as a script to slightly automate the process for other users.

The problem that I have is that where I have a formula in my small table to add a variable date to the values when they are first copied and pasted there `"=if(D11>0,$D$7,"")`. Unfortunately this inclusion of formula causes a disruption to my main task by being included when being copied even though remaining blank and then causing gaps and run errors with the code I found somewhere online.

```
      function getDynamicRows(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('C11:J');
  var data = sourceRange.getValues(); // Array of arrays [[Row1],[Row1],[Row3]]

  // add data to next empty row in the static sheet. 
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('2020 Data');
  data.forEach(function(row){
    targetSheet.appendRow(row)
  })}
```

Any help I can get with this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of `getValues()`

Using `getDisplayValues()` will make sure that you will copy the values the way you see them in the source sheet without any interference with formulas

Sample:

```
      function getDynamicRows(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('C11:J');
  var data = sourceRange.getDisplayValues(); // Array of arrays [[Row1],[Row1],[Row3]]

  // add data to next empty row in the static sheet. 
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('2020 Data');
  data.forEach(function(row){
    targetSheet.appendRow(row)
  })}
```